# Chrome for Android's media notifications disappear

Tags: notifications, chrome-for-android, media-player

Chrome and other browsers show media in the notifications area automatically. I use to be able to switch apps and continue playing the media. Now, when the app is no longer active, the media notification disappears.

I don't know if I changed a setting somewhere or if an update broke something, any tips are appreciated.

Here's a similar question:
https://superuser.com/questions/1581481/firefox-stopped-playing-media-in-the-background